# Why is jpype not loading the specified .jar

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, jpype

I cannot load the intended jar. The java class path is not set (None)

I tried to connect to an oracle database with the JDBC driver, but the import of the ojdbc8.jar is failing

Here is my code

```
jpype.addClassPath('ojdbc8.jar')
jpype.startJVM()
```

The JVM is starting, but the class path is none

```
print(jpype.getClassPath())
print(jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("java.class.path"))
print(jpype.JClass("driver.class.Name"))
```

The output is:

```
D:\06_Python_Programme\WPy64-3740\notebooks\ojdbc8.jar
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ac29a5fbe025> in <module>
      2 print(jpype.getClassPath())
      3 print(jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("java.class.path"))
----> 4 print(jpype.JClass("driver.class.Name"))
      5 print(jpype.JClass('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'))

D:\06_Python_Programme\WPy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py in __new__(cls, jc, loader, initialize)
     97 
     98         # Pass to class factory to create the type
---> 99         return _jpype._getClass(jc)
    100 
    101 

TypeError: Class driver.class.Name is not found
```

If I try the following, the problem stays the same:

```
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Djava.class.path=/ojdbc8.jar')
```

I would guess that it is an easy fix, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `jpype.JClass("driver.class.Name")`, `driver.class.Name` seems like an *examplar* that you need to replace with the actual driver name (for Oracle, `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but shouldn't the `jpype.getClassPath()` still return the class path?

Comment: @Seb I don't know jpype, but judging by the first line of output shown, it did return the class path. I'm not sure why you're asking though: trying to load a class that does not exist on the class path (`driver.class.Name`) will fail, and ojdbc8.jar does not include a class called `driver.class.Name`.